# Error; java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to create a login page for a java web app using MySQL. When I run the code I receive this exception; java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        `String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        MyDb1 db = new MyDb1();
      Connection con = db.getCon();
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select uid,email,pass from register where email = '"+email+"' and  pass = '"+pass+"'");
    if ((rs.next())) {

        String uid = rs.getString("uid");
        response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/FinalYearProjec/userprofile.jsp");  


          HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
          session.setAttribute("name",uid); } 

else {
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Incorrect.html");
                rd.forward(request, response);


 }

  } catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Logi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,   null, ex);
         }
```

Comment: Side note - please don’t use String concatenation in your sql queries - [it is incredibly unsafe.](https://www.xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

your error is because you are redirecting before you set the session attribute:

```
 response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/FinalYearProjec/userprofile.jsp");  


  HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
  session.setAttribute("name",uid); }
```

Whenever you redirect or forward the user to a different page, you need to make sure that you do any actions want to do before you forward or redirect. So just change it like this:

```
  HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
  session.setAttribute("name",uid); } 

 response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/FinalYearProjec/userprofile.jsp");  //put this last
```

Here's your code cleaned up, and with the stuff you don't need taken out (using preparedstatement here because manually building your statement isn't safe as a comment has mentioned already. )

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    MyDb1 db = new MyDb1();

    String url = "Incorrect.html";    
    try(Connection con = db.getCon()){

         PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select uid,email,pass from register where email = ? and pass = ?;"); 
         pst.setString(1, email); //set first '?'
         pst.setString(2, pass); //set second '?'
         ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {

            url = "userprofile.jsp"; //override url string

            String uid = rs.getString("uid");

            HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
            session.setAttribute("name",uid); 

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
    rd.forward(request, response);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However when I run that code I receive this error; HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL. Would you know why this is occurring? Thanks

Comment: It means your servlet doesn't have a doPost method.

Comment: Create a doPost and call processRequest from your doPost or move this code into a doPost method..  or change the method on your form to a get and move the code to the doGet method